# Accidentally Typing Sensitive Information In Shell (BASH)

Tags: bash, command-history

**What is(are) the recommended approach(s) to recover from typing sensitive information (password/passphrase clear text) in BASH?**

**Example:**
Accidentally typing in a password in clear text when a normal command is expected.

What steps should be taken to guarantee (for most common Linux distributions and configurations) that traces of the sensitive data has been erased?

Comment: I did lookup  how to clear bash history. But, I am not sure that this is enough.

Comment: Change the "leaked" password. Or relax and don't give a hoot about it -- just imagine that you're working in the government ;-)